# IBatis truncates date on calling pl/sql procedure

Tags: java, plsql, ibatis

I have this code on pl/sql :

```
              SELECT TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') 
              into v_dateSysDate
              from dual;
```

When I try to print the value of v_dateSysDate on pl/sql like this :

```
 dbms_output.put_line('v_dateSysDate : ' ||  v_dateSysDate);
```

I get :

```
v_dateSysDate : 18-OTT-15  15:51:03
```

Instead, when i try to call the procedure on pl/sql (From IBATIS) that executes the select above i get the following result :

```
v_dateSysdate : 18-OTT-15
```

So IBatis truncates the date giving me only the date without the hours,minutes and seconds of the sysdate. 
How can I solve my problem, to get the complete date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the type of the variable you are binding with?

Comment: I am binding the date with a String like this : <parameter property="msgDisplay"   javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="OUT" />

Comment: And what is the type defined for `v_dateSysdate` in your procedure?

Comment: v_dateSysDate                 date;

Comment: At the procedure i do a calculation like this : floor(sysdate - (time inserting a row)). But since he gets floor(18-oct-15 - 18-oct-15) he gives me 0. When I Call the procedure from oracle sql developer i get the seconds and not 0 (  floor (18-oct-15 16:13:56  - 18-oct-15  16:10:56)) giving as result 180 (seconds, or 3 minutes)

Comment: Try changing your `v_dateSysdate` to timestamp